# Set Pandas Dataframe Value with another list of Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I have a data frame with column A, df['A']
   df is something like

```
index    A
1        nan
2        nan
3        nan
4        nan
5        nan
```

2. I have a list of True/False value which is a mask of data frame, where True means the value should be replaced.

```
mask = [False, True, False, True, True]
```

3. I have another list of value which I want to use to replace the df['A'] with index from 2 -

```
value = [1, 3, 2]
```

The result I want is -

```
index    A
1        nan
2        1
3        nan
4        3
5        2
```

I try to use df['A'][mask] = value
But it's not working.
Anyone can help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for working with [slice of DataFrame, not copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

```
df.loc[mask, 'A'] = value
print (df)
     A
1  NaN
2  1.0
3  NaN
4  3.0
5  2.0
```